VScode complaining about a missing __ function, that exists
I'm having a lot of Function __ not found. in VScode. The thing is, I'm using CakePHP 5 and that function is actually there, and it's doing its job.
Another error that I'm having is Constant WWW_ROOT not found . This is also something that is defined and it's standard in CakePHP.
I suppose that the problem lies in VScode itself that for some reason can't see the definitions, but how can I solve this?
